# number of integers less than the input that are nearly palindromes (if you just change one index) PYTHON

Tags: python, palindrome

```
n=int(input())

def palindrome(x):

    m=str(x)
    l=len(m)
    if l==1 or l==2 or l==3: 
        return True
    if l>3:
        for i in m:
            for j in range (0,10):
                k=m.replace(str(i),str(j))
                if k==k[::-1]:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
def almost(n):

    count=0
    for x in range (10,n):
        if str(x)!=str(x)[::-1] and palindrome(x):
            count+=1
    return count
print (almost(n))
```

Here's my code so far. It's not working for all cases where the input has more than 3 digits. For instance, it won't let me input numbers with more than 5 digits in the terminal. It just goes to a new line so I have to open a new tab. I tried to input 1000000 and it didn't yield an output. It should've given me 43,011. The code has to give a number of integers that are NOT palindromes but would be if your just change one digit like 14351, if you change 4 to 5 it'd be a palindrome. So the input might be something like 23 and the output would be 11 (since the numbers less than 23 that would be palindromes if you change one digit are 10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21). The one-digit numbers are excluded since they are already palindromes. Thank!

Comment: Noted! Thank you!

Comment: *just change one digit like 14456, if you change 4 to 5 it'd be a palindrome* - how exactly?

Comment: It's not though is it...

Comment: Sorry. Ignore that. If it's 14351, which is a palindrome and you change 4 into 5 then it'll be a palindrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of replacing digits and testing if it's a palindrome, check if you've already seen a location that differs between the left and right side. If more than one digit differs, you can't make it a palindrome by just changing one digit.

Since we're comparing the left side against the right side, we only need to iterate half the string (to `l/2`). And since we're dealing with integers here, we'll end up stopping before the middle digit if there's an odd number of digits.

```
def palindrome(x):
    m = str(x)
    l = len(m)

    if m == m[::-1]:
        return False

    if l < 4:
        return True

    already_wrong = False

    for i in range(0, l/2):
        # -1 since the index is 0 based and l is one larger than the last index
        if m[i] != m[l-i-1]:
            # more than one digit differs? (i.e. we've already been here?)
            if already_wrong:
                return False

            already_wrong = True

    return True

print(palindrome(14456))
print(palindrome(15556))
print(palindrome(14351))
print(palindrome(166666))
print(palindrome(131666))
```

outputs

```
False
True
True
True
False
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Comment: This gives for `sum(palindrome(n) for n in range(1000000))` an answer of 45010 though

Comment: A sample of which are considered "almost palindromes": `[665566, 99899, 634436, 151151, 96269, 839938, 373, 232232, 103301, 64546]` so looks like this needs to exclude *exact* palindromes

Comment: Sure! I got confused with the text in the original question, where it's assumed that _anything_ below 4 is an "almost" palindrome, even if its an palindrome. To get the same answer as in the question (43011), I've added an explicit check.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to work out if only 2 digits are out of sequence between the string and the string in reverse - then it follows you can swap one digit to make a palindrome... This also excludes single digits and palindromes themselves (as 0 digits will be different), eg:

```
def is_almost_palindrome(n):
    s = str(n)
    if sum(a != b for a, b in zip(s, reversed(s))) == 2:
        return True
    return False
```

Then you get your count as:

```
almost_palindromes = sum(is_almost_palindrome(n) for n in range(1000000))
# 43011
```